# Displaying elements inline with HTML?

Tags: html, css, inline

I am trying to create a web application and in it I want these two fields to display inline(check the Image below). Now the BugID is an `<input>` element and the Description is a `<textarea>`. Currently I have this:

```
<div class="some">
  <h3 id="title1">Bug ID:<span class="required">*</span></h3>
  <h3 id="title">Enter Description:<span class="required">*</span></h3>
  <br/>
  <div class="inputs">
  <input size="8" maxlength="8" name="BugID" type="text" id="BugID" placeholder="Bug ID" style="width:100px" />
  <textarea rows="5" id="Summary" name="summary" placeholder="Please Enter a Summary of the Bug" ></textarea>
   </div>
   </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.inputs input, textarea{
      display:inline;
}
```

Is this wrong? How should I be doing this?

[image: Current Implementation]

Comment: I thought `<input>`s were inline by default.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Old comment, I know. But `<input>` elements are `inline-block` by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
   .inputs input, textarea{
          display:inline;
          float:left;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#BugID, #Summary
{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

And add an extra div after both fields that has class="clear"

**Edit:** Use the below sample, I've just tested it and it will align the titles and fields inline for you

```
<style>
#BugID, #Summary, h3
{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

#BugID, #title1
{
    width: 100px;
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
</style>

<div class="some">
  <h3 id="title1">Bug ID:<span class="required">*</span></h3>
  <h3 id="title">Enter Description:<span class="required">*</span></h3>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="inputs">
  <input size="8" maxlength="8" name="BugID" type="text" id="BugID" placeholder="Bug ID" style="width:100px" />
  <textarea rows="5" id="Summary" name="summary" placeholder="Please Enter a Summary of the Bug" ></textarea>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will probably get shot down for this, but personally I would use a `table` because your layout is looking like a table.

Comment: Tables should only be used for tabular data, not for aligning form elements. :-P

Comment: ahh the CSS purists are coming! Am I allowed to use tables to eat from? :P

Comment: You can eat of the table if you want, I prefer using a plate. :-P

Answer (score 0):

you can use `table` tag. In this case you will need 2 rows and 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` are inline elements by default.  You need to change the `<h3>`s to inline (as those are block elements).

I also suggest not using `<h3>` tags for anything other than what they are meant for.  They are meant to denote headers/subheaders, not for formatting text.  May I suggest the `<label>` tag?

```
<div class="some">
  <label id="title1" for="BugID">Bug ID:<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <label id="title" for="Summary">Enter Description:<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <br/>
  <div class="inputs">
     <input size="8" maxlength="8" name="BugID" type="text" id="BugID" placeholder="Bug ID" style="width:100px" />
     <textarea rows="5" id="Summary" name="summary" placeholder="Please Enter a Summary of the Bug" ></textarea>
  </div>
</div>​​​​​​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vW3GL/

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest a better option. Update your markup structure to a more structure one. May  be something like this

```
<div class="some">
    <div class="input">
      <h3 id="title1">Bug ID:<span class="required">*</span></h3>
      <input size="8" maxlength="8" name="BugID" type="text" id="BugID" placeholder="Bug ID" style="width:100px" />
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <h3 id="title">Enter Description:<span class="required">*</span></h3>
      <textarea rows="5" id="Summary" name="summary" placeholder="Please Enter a Summary of the Bug" ></textarea>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Now the **fix**: CSS

```
.input { display: inline-block; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; }​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RrB2N/)